# How to replace Default SqlServerConventionSetBuilder by custom implemented in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I add new PropertyAttributeConvention for EF Core:

```
public class RowGuidColumnAttributeConvention : PropertyAttributeConvention<RowGuidColumnAttribute>{
public override InternalPropertyBuilder Apply(InternalPropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, RowGuidColumnAttribute attribute, MemberInfo clrMember)
{
    propertyBuilder.HasAnnotation("RowGuidColumn", "TRUE", ConfigurationSource.DataAnnotation);
    return propertyBuilder;
}}
```

And inherit from SqlServerConventionSetBuilder to add this Convention:

```
public class DefaultCoreConventionSetBuilder : SqlServerConventionSetBuilder
{
    public DefaultCoreConventionSetBuilder(IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper, ICurrentDbContext currentContext, IDbSetFinder setFinder) 
        : base(typeMapper, currentContext, setFinder)
    {    }

   public override ConventionSet AddConventions(ConventionSet conventionSet)
    {
        base.AddConventions(conventionSet);

        var rowGuid = new RowGuidColumnAttributeConvention();
        conventionSet.PropertyAddedConventions.Add(rowGuid);
        conventionSet.PropertyFieldChangedConventions.Add(rowGuid);

        return conventionSet;
    }
}
```

Then replace it in Startup file:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddScoped<SqlServerConventionSetBuilder, DefaultCoreConventionSetBuilder>()
            .AddScoped<SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator, DefaultSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator>()
            .AddDbContext<DataContext>();
```

but on result no any convention added to model create in migration.
can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this,

In Startup File:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
```

And in dbcontext override OnConfiguring:

```
optionsBuilder
            .ReplaceService<IConventionSetBuilder, DefaultCoreConventionSetBuilder>()
            .ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, DefaultSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator>()
            .UseSqlServer(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:DbConnection"]);
```